# How to changing the language of cmd terminal (chcp is not working)

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, terminal, cmd.exe

I am writing a script that is responsible to read command output from Windows terminal.

The intent is to read the command line output using the command "`sc query <service_name>`" and based on regex, consume and resend a more concise data to the user.

The problem is that given the user language, the output content can change completely. I should not write a script that will interpret the "`sc query`" in all languages possible. Better to set a common language before running the script, so I can work on a single output format, no matter are the user language.

The first thing that comes when searching is the "`chcp`" command. But it does not works for me, and that are not much further when search for when the command does not works.

You can check in the print screen my trials to change the language (twice) and a sample for output service outputted in Portuguese.

Sample output of the trial on changing cmd language by chcp:

[image]

What I need to do? Is there some other way to change the cmd language or I need to do something else to make the `chcp` command to work?

Comment: chcp changes the codepage used for displaying text. It has NOTHING to do with the system display language, which can not be changed without doing a reboot (and in many cases is not changeable arbitrarily anyway because the language packages (LIP's) for the new language need to be installed).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

What do you have in mind I have no idea but I understand that the output from `SC` command will take place in English in the items that describe the status of the processes in whatever language the system is in, which I suggest doing something that intercepts the output in a predictive way to possible statuses, and transform/translate to desire language.

Answer (score 0):

`CHCP` changes the encoding not the language. There is no command to do that. If you have installed multiple languages you have an icon to change the language on the System Notification area.

So this command doesn't do what I think. Why doesn't it do what I think?

Comment: I cannot ask to my users to change the whole system language by system notification everytime they desires to runs my script, right? It MUST be something done on command line and should affects only stuffs in the same terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

My suggested approach, found in an [S.O. answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987266/), is to *target very specific things which are locale-independent*. In this case, for obtaining service status from `sc.exe`, the goal is to get the integer which identifies the state (which was found to be independent of active language and, therefore, robust).

Short example (additional details in the linked answer):

```bat
for /F "skip=3 tokens=3" %%i in ('""%windir%\system32\sc.exe" query "W32Time" 2^>nul"') do (
  if "%%i"=="4" (
    echo 'W32Time' service is running
    goto :SkipRemainingIterations
  )
)
:SkipRemainingIterations
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the language of the CMD terminal when the "chcp" command is not working, you can try the following steps:

Open the CMD terminal: Launch the CMD terminal on your Windows computer.

Check language settings: Confirm the current language settings of your operating system. Go to the "Control Panel" or "Settings" and navigate to the "Language" or "Region" options. Ensure that the desired language is selected as the default language.

Modify system locale: If the language change does not reflect in CMD, you may need to modify the system locale. In the language settings, look for the "Administrative" or "Advanced" tab. Locate the "Change system locale" option and select the desired language. This will change the language settings for non-Unicode programs.

Restart the computer: After modifying the system locale, it's recommended to restart your computer. This will ensure that the language changes take effect.

By following these steps, you should be able to change the language of the CMD terminal.